# Join the data returned from a stored procedure to the tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I want to retrieve data for two columns `StockLocaton` and `AdditionalInfo` from the `IdlerStockLocations` table. I've written something to create that join, but it doesn't return any data if there is no corresponding data in the `IdlerStockLocation` table (and even if there is, it will only return the data returned from the stored procedure execution `procDashboard_IdlerFailureGrid`). I want to know why this might be happening here.

```
 var tags = _context.procDashboard_IdlerFailureGrid(level, id, gridFilter, idlerFilter)
    .Select(x => x)
    .AsQueryable()
    .Project()
    .To<IdlerTagModel>(m => m
        .Ignore(i => i.EnforceUserDropdown)
        .Ignore(i => i.FrameTo)
        .Ignore(i => i.FrameFrom)
        .Map(s => s.PartNumber, d => d.PartNumber)
        .Map(s => s.IsAtRisk, d => Convert.ToBoolean(d.IsAtRisk)))
    .ToList();

tags = (from tag in tags
        join area in _context.vwAreas on tag.AreaID equals area.AreaID
        join idler in _context.Idlers on new { BID = (int?)area.BusinessID, PartNum = tag.PartNumber } equals new { BID = idler.BusinessID, PartNum = idler.Name }
        join stockLocation in _context.IdlerStockLocations on new { IID = idler.IdlerID, AID = tag.AreaID } equals new { IID = stockLocation.IdlerID, AID = stockLocation.AreaID }
        where idler.IsActive && !idler.IsDeleted && stockLocation.IsActive && stockLocation.RecordStatusID == Constant.RecordStatuses.Current
        select tag).ToList();
```

Since the properties are already available in `IdlerTagModel`, I believe I don't have to select it explicitly again, right?

When I'm doing this same step on DB using left outer join it works.

Comment: Your `.Select(x => x).AsQueryable()` steps are redundant and can be removed - unless `_context.procDashboard_IdlerFailureGrid` _doesnt_ return an `IQueryable<T>` or `DbSet<T>` - can you shed some light on that?

Comment: Is the sproc configured in EF as returning an entity or returning a complex-type? Are you using navigation-properties? Exactly what version of EF are you using?